# Implementation blind deconvolution algorithm based on vector

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, deconvolution

I was studying deconvolution,
and stumbled upon [Richardson-Lucy deconvolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richardson%E2%80%93Lucy_deconvolution),
and I found [implementation of this deconvolution](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.restoration.html#skimage.restoration.richardson_lucy) in Python.
I got the vector of volacity of moving object and I am wonder if there is a solution to generate a PSF (Point Spread Function) example of this PSF: [image: psf example]
I have a velocity and length vector of a moving object and I am wondering if there is a solution to generate a PSF from the data from the length or velocity vector of the object. 
 If there is no such solution, is there a way to generate a reasonable PSF?

Regards

Comment: Is the velocity of the object constant (within the frame)? Is the distance of the object to the camera constant (within the frame)? If so, then you can represent your vector as a distance moved in pixels within the exposure time of the frame, and all pixels will have moved in the same way and by this same distance. Otherwise you cannot apply deconvolution. Now all you need to do is draw a line with that length, that's your PSF.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I don't quite understand.
For example if the speed is 10px / s and the object is moving horizontally to the left, should I draw line 10px horizontally? The table itself that will represent the PSF should then be 10x10px and a white (255, 255, 255) line going through the center? Or from center to right 10px? Or is 2x10px enough? Is it really that simple?

Comment: 1x10px is enough. It really is that simple! // Any zero pixels in the PSF can be left out, so you can crop the drawn line to its minimal bounding box if you like. // If you draw the line from center to right, you'll get the same result as if drawing from left to right edges, but shifted (as long as the line is the same length). That is, shifting the drawing in the PSF causes a shift of the output. I presume a shift is irrelevant?

Comment: Yeah, shift is irrelevant. I'm going to implement it and test it myself. 
Anyway, wow, I am impressed, thank you for your help.